# Get a value from a table (using a criteria) and store in another table in one command

Tags: database, postgresql, dml

I try to update a value in a table with the sum of values that satisfy a criteria from another table.

In the first command, I would like to get the number of shared articles (3 here):

```
db=# select article_id,liked,shared, COUNT(article_id) FROM social WHERE article_id > 0 GROUP BY article_id,liked,shared HAVING article_id=2087 AND shared=true;
 article_id | liked | shared | count 
------------+-------+--------+-------
       2087 | f     | t      |     3
(1 row)
```

I have another table and I need to put this value (3) in the right column:

```
db=# SELECT article_id,shared FROM articles WHERE article_id=2087;
 article_id | shared 
------------+--------
       2087 |       
(1 row)
```

I can do that with two commands in Python, but I'm sure there is a better way to do that in one SQL request ?

Edit:

I tried this command :

```
db=# UPDATE articles SET shared=subquery.count FROM ( SELECT count(article_id) FROM social WHERE article_id=2087 AND shared=true) AS subquery WHERE article_id=2087;
UPDATE 1

db=# SELECT article_id,shared FROM articles WHERE article_id=2087;
 article_id | shared 
------------+--------
       2087 |      3
(1 row)
```

I just need to set one time the article_id and I might be good. Any advice ?

Comment: Put that into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would wrap the counts in a CTE and do the updates off of the results of the CTE:

```
with counts as (
  select article_id,liked,shared, COUNT(article_id) as article_count
  FROM social
  WHERE article_id > 0
  GROUP BY article_id,liked,shared
  HAVING article_id=2087 AND shared=true
)
update articles a
set shared = c.article_count
from counts c
where a.article_id = c.article_id
```

A couple of other nitpicky things...

1. `HAVING article_id=2087 and shared=true` would be better moved to the `where` clause.  Sure, this will work, but `HAVING` is normally reserved for aggregate functions (`having count (*) > 1` or `having sum (qty) = 0`.  The advantage of moving this to the where clause is that you avoid grabbing and aggregating data that ends up being filtered out.  I'm not sure about this, but it might even make better use of indexing.
2. `shared=true` can be shortened to `shared`.  You may not like the loss of clarity on what that means, so take or leave it.
3. There is an inconsistecy in the first query and what you want to update...  specifically, the initial query may return multiple results because you are not grouping by just the article_id -- so you may get numerous results for that same article_id.  This construct you are trusting it will update the right one.  Is that what you meant?

Summary of those three suggestions with some assumptions:

```
with counts as (
  select article_id, COUNT(article_id) as article_count
  FROM social
  WHERE article_id > 0 and article_id=2087 AND shared
  GROUP BY article_id
)
update articles a
set shared = c.article_count
from counts c
where a.article_id = c.article_id
```

I realize `article_id > 0` and `article_id=2087` are redundant, but I assumed the latter was a test case you would eventually remove so you could update all records at once.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the explanation ! I learned a lot with your answer. Yes, I need to group_by as you said, and the >0 is just for testing. The final function will trigger on a given specific "article_id" and not for all ids.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback; I'm glad it was helpful.  Sometimes people just want the short answer, so you never know...